# Unable to build production build for vue with webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

When I run production build with webpack for vue it ends with

```
CssSyntaxError: /css/app.css:15612:13: Missed semicolon
```

The above line in app.css looks like

[image]

The package.json doesn't have moment but have chartjs library which uses moment.js.

Comment: This error is generated by babel plugin @vue/babel-present-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem related to scss file.
The Problem got resolved with updating version of webpack and laravel-mix.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create js-variables in css files. Therefore, you should have another file (JavaScript file) in which you link the `css`-file as asset.

Comment: Yes correct but this is the bundle file generated by webpack in public folder. Same things also created when running npm run dev.